# Display TimeSpan timer on UI Unity

Tags: c#, timer, monodevelop, unity-game-engine

I have code that runs a timer in my Unity project, the timer runs through multiple scenes using DateTime, I'm trying to make the time visible in the editor so that I can make the countdown visible on the UI.

Here is the script for the countdown;

```
public static class GlobalCountDown
{
    static DateTime TimeStarted;
    static TimeSpan TotalTime;

    public static void StartCountDown(TimeSpan totalTime)
    {
        TimeStarted = DateTime.UtcNow;
        TotalTime = totalTime;
    }

    public static TimeSpan TimeLeft
    {
        get
        {
            var result = TotalTime - (DateTime.UtcNow - TimeStarted);
            if (result.TotalSeconds <= 0)
                return TimeSpan.Zero;           
                 return result;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the call to the script that I make in each scene to carry the timer;

```
GlobalCountDown.StartCountDown (TimeSpan.FromSeconds (8));
```

The functionality is working, but I'm not sure how to make it visible in the UI, I've tried using the following but I'm not having much luck;

```
string timeLeft = GlobalCountDown.TimeLeft.TotalSeconds().ToString("D2");
```

Any help or advice with this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use UI Text object.

```
[SerializeField] Private Text countdownTimer; // will require UnityEngine.UI at top
```

Update `countdownTimer`'s `text` property every time you change/reduce the timer value.

```
countdownTimer.text = your_time_left_var.ToString();
```

Comment: Fantastic, the timer is now displayed on the UI, and will continue to countdown between scenes. At the moment the timer displays as 00:00:08 when I set the timer to have 8 seconds in total, do you know a way to only show the last 2 numbers, the timer will never go above 10 seconds.

The following code is what got the timer visible

 [SerializeField] 
 private Text countdownTimer;

and

countdownTimer.text = GlobalCountDown.TimeLeft.ToString();

Comment: It depends on your TimeLeft type. If it's just integer counter that counts seconds then it should be just just integer output. If your TimeLeft is coming as  a hour:minute:second format then you should avoid  formatting that way in that method. Result will show just the seconds. For shortcut use `String.Trim()`